# Should a python abstract base class inherit from object

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, abstract-class

The standard document about [abc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html), and other tutorials I read all use examples that defines a abstract base class without inheriting from object.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        ...
    def __len__(self):
        ...
    def get_iterator(self):
        return iter(self)

class MyIterable:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def __iter__(self):
        while False:
            yield None
```

In the past I always let my class inherit object to have new-style class. Should I do the same with ABC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring the metaclass of `MyIterable` to be `ABCMeta` ensures that instances of `MyIterable` (or more appropriately, subclasses of `MyIterable` since it is an Abstract Base Class) will be the "new" style.  If you were to create an instance of a subclass of `MyIterable` as seen below, it would behave as a new style class.

```
class SubIterable(MyIterable):
    def __iter__(self):
        # your implementation here
        ...

>>> type(SubIterable())
<type '__main__'.MyIterable>
```

If `MyIterable` were indeed an "old" style class, `type(SubIterable())` would return `<type 'instance'>`